# R: View all fields of a class

Tags: r

I'm using the twitteR package for R. I've got an object `redDressTweets[[1]]`; when I do

```
class(redDressTweets[[1]])
```

I get back

```
[1] "status"
attr(,"package")
[1] "twitteR"
```

So I believe that `redDressTweets[[1]]`'s class is "status".
When I type `redDressTweets[[1]]$` into RStudio, it suggests a list of fields. I'd like to be able to be able to output this list onto the console, how do I do that?

So far, I've tried `summary(redDressTweets[[1]])` and `redDressTweets[[1]][0,]` but those don't do it. What I'd like is something like `df[0,]` for a data frame, but for a class.

Comment: Can you use `names(redDressTweets[[1]])`?

Comment: @rosscova Returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try sapply(redDressTweets, class). This will show the classes in your dataset and then you can extract accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I know that the class of the elements of `redDressTweets` is `status`. I want to know the fields of `status`

Comment: Can you give some example dataset. I can try but am not sure. Thanks.